# Add comma separated value to separate lines in VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi guys I have the following code where I look over a json file and add the data to a table.

I want the data from `product.refrencing_category_ids` to be output in on separate lines instead being in one line like this:

```
bc-men,bc-men-fashion,bc-men-underwear
```

I would like it to look like:

```
bc-men,
bc-men-fashion,
bc-men-underwear
```

How would i go about doing that? Would I need another for loop for the `product.refrencing_category_ids`?

My code look like this:

```
<template>
    <div>

        <h1>Category Assignment</h1>

        <table class="table">
            <tr class="table-header">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Primary category</th>
                <th>Refrencing categories</th>
                <th>Add</th>
            <tr>
            <tr class="product" v-for="product in products">
                <td class="product__item"><input required type="text" v-model="product.id"></td>
                <td class="product__item"><input required type="text" name="fname" v-model="product.name"></td>
                <td class="product__item">
                    <input required type="text" name="fname" v-model="product.primary_category_id">
                </td>
                <td class="product__item">
                    <input required type="text" name="fname" v-model="product.refrencing_category_ids">
                </td>
                <td class="product__item">
                    <button v-on:click="product.quantity += 1">
                        Add
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h2>Total inventory: {{ totalProducts }}</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ProductEnrichment',
        data () {
            return {
                products: [],
                productHeadline: 'Product Flow Tool'
            }
        },
        computed: {
            totalProducts () {
                return this.products.reduce((sum, product) => {
                    return sum + product.quantity
                }, 0)
            }
        },
        created () {
            fetch('https://www.fennefoss.dk/product-request.json')
            //fetch('./sample.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.products = json.products
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to another loop with `v-for`. To make the list item reactive, you need to update the original `data` and not the `computed` one. Something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      product: {
        refrencing_category_ids: 'bc-men,bc-men-fashion,bc-men-underwear'
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    remove(idx) {
      let items = this.product.refrencing_category_ids.split(',');

      let removed = items.splice(idx, 1);

      this.product.refrencing_category_ids = items.join(',');
    }
  },

  computed: {
    refCatIds() {
      return this.product.refrencing_category_ids.split(',');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(id, index) in refCatIds" :key="index">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="remove(index)">{{id}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably not the best idea if you need to maintain the order though.

Answer (score -1):

Replace all of the commas with `\n` (newline character)

```js
let string = "bc-men,bc-men-fashion,bc-men-underwear"
console.log(string.replace(/,/g, '\n'))
```

Comment: That would only work if the container had PRE styling

Comment: However this is pure Vanilla Javascript and wont work as reactive once i start adding and removing values to the list.